# Elements in the view controller are loading slowly

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, mpvolumeview

When I present my view controller the elements(Imageview, buttons, slide, **MPVolume view**) are loading slowly. First of all empty screen comes up and elements are loading one by one.. What should be the reason for this?

Comment: sounds like a great time to use Instruments, maybe starting with the Time Profiler.

Comment: what do you mean by "loading"? - appearing on the screen?

Comment: do you have network requests during that time?

Comment: @Injectios No network requests..

Comment: @Injectios yes appearing on the screen